# Manipulate returned objects from $HTTP in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date, compare, momentjs

I have a Database with a lot of items where i need to grab the item.expire date and compare it to **Todays date** So i get something like "5 days back before expire".

I got all that working but i dont know how to pass my Number **5** "5 days back before expire"
To my ng-repeat.

```
 .controller('itemController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Items',
    function($scope, $http, Items) {

        var promise = Items.get();
        promise.then(
            function(itemData) {

                //Return data object to the ng-repeat
                $scope.items = itemData.data;


                angular.forEach(itemData.data, function(oneItem) {

                    var currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    var a = moment(oneItem.expire);
                    var b = moment( currentDate );

                    $scope.items.expire = a.diff(b, 'days');
                });
            },
            function(errorItemData) {
                $log.error('failure loading item', errorItemData);
                console.log("error");
            });
```

my HTML

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchItem" class="certificateListItems">


            <td> @{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@{{ item.issuer }}</td>

            <td><a href="{{ URL::to('items/view_file/')  }}/@{{ item.id }} " target="_blank">Download</a></td>

            <td><img ng-click="showBox(item)" ng-src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons/mail_outgoing.png') }}"
                     alt="Send mail"/></td>
            <td>
                @{{ item.expire  }}
            </td>
            <td>1st: @{{ item.alarm1 | date : 'shortDate' }}<br>2nd: @{{ item.alarm2 | date : 'shortDate' }}</td>
            <td>
                <a ng-click="editItem(item)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> -
                <a ng-click="deleteItem(item)" href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
            </td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item has it own expiration date. But your loop stores the expiration time in a single variable:

```
// $scope.items is an array of items.
$scope.items = itemData.data;

angular.forEach(itemData.data, function(oneItem) {

    var currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var a = moment(oneItem.expire);
    var b = moment( currentDate );

    // this sets a property 'exire' on the array of data
    $scope.items.expire = a.diff(b, 'days');
});
```

It should instead be

```
$scope.items = itemData.data;

angular.forEach(itemData.data, function(oneItem) {

    var currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var a = moment(oneItem.expire);
    var b = moment( currentDate );

    // this sets a property 'exire' on the array of data
    oneItem.daysBeforeExpiration = a.diff(b, 'days');
});
```

and, in the HTML:

```
{{ item.daysBeforeExpiration }}
```

Comment: Wow JB, Thanks so much, this has been a headache for some days now :)